# PHPMailer inserts data into my database only null values

Tags: php, sql, phpmailer

I used the libraby PHPMailer to send email from my form, which i'm able to, but the problem is, i want the data that is typed in to be inserted into my database, which is not happening, the only thing that happens is that it inserts only null values and it doesn't show the success message that i made.

Php:

```
<?php
$result="";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail -> Host='smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Porto = 587;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure='tls';
    $mail->Username='****';
    $mail->Password='****';

    $mail->setFrom($_POST['EmailReser']);
    $mail->addAddress('filipajoao1933@gmail.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo($_POST['EmailReser']);

    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject='Reversa';
    $mail->Body='<h1>Name:'.$_POST['NomeReser'].'<br>Email:'.$_POST['EmailReser'].'<br>Message: '.$_POST['MensagemR'].'</h1>';

    if(!$mail->send()){
        $result="Something went wrong. Please try again";
    }
    else{
        $result="Thanks".$_POST['NomeReser']."for contacting us. We´ll get back to you soon!";

    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Reservas (NomeReser, EmailReser, MensagemR) VALUES ('$Nome','$Email', '$Mensagem')";
    $res=$lig->query($sql);
}

?>
```

Comment: You never define those variables. You're also open for SQL injection. Make sure you use prepared statements and parameter binding for whichever API you're using. Here are the instructions for [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: It seems you have just posted your username and password, you'll want to change them immediately.

Comment: I don't see `'$Nome','$Email', '$Mensagem'` defined anywhere. Even if you're posting them from the form, you need to either use the `$_POST` variable directly in the `INSERT` statement or you need to set the ones you're using.